# get data in sql from from date to to date

Tags: sql, date

I want to write the stored procedure which would give me the data within the rage of date. I can not use 'Between'  , it is giving data between the range , i need within the range means from 1-jan-2011 to 30-jan-2011 (data of 30 jan must be included) how to do this with query/ SP

Comment: BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is greater than or equal to the value of begin_expression and less than or equal to the value of end_expression.

Comment: ashish.chotalia is saying `BETWEEN` works the way you want, not the way you think it does. It includes the end points.

Comment: sorry catcall, I tried with Between , but unfortunately it is not including last bound.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE somecol >= '2011-01-01' AND somecol <= '2011-01-30'
```

Comment: Exact syntax may depend on what RDBMS you're using, you didn't tag this question with one. But you should be able to compare the column to the two boundaries of your range without `BETWEEN`.

Comment: this means "between " not include last bound date ?

Comment: I did not say anything about the behavior of `BETWEEN`, I showed you how to do the query without `BETWEEN` since you asked not to use that.

Comment: but observe the question again, my meaning is Between does not include the last range in fetch records. let say list is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and i i request for integers between 2 to 7 then , if i used here BETWEEN , it would returns 2,3,4,5,6 (not 7 itself). well your solution have solved issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  a ">= AND <" condition instead of BETWEEN.

Assuming you pass in @DateTo as the end date you want to INCLUDE:

```
SELECT Something
FROM YourTable
WHERE DateField >= @DateFrom
    AND DateField < DATEADD(dd, 1, @DateTo)
```

e.g. pass in @DateFrom = '20110101' and @DateTo = '20110130' then this will return all records from 1st Jan to 30th Jan inclusive.

Comment: If there can never be any data at the time of `00:00:00`, then I believe it is safe to use BETWEEN too, i.e. `...WHERE DateField BETWEEN @DateFrom AND DATEADD(dd, 1, @DateTo)` (assuming the datetime vars are only dates, i.e. without time parts).